# Parsing symbols when importing into wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

We are importing a csv file of data, and in the description there are cross symbols etc, and most of the description is not imported. Does anyone recognize these symbols and how would I work with the fields to make it display with line breaks and lists.  I assume that's what the symbols represent.

Here's an example of the description:

```
DUTIES OF THE RESOURCE:
†
To assist in all activities related to the conduct of a staffing activity including but not limited to the following:
ï screening candidates based on application material;
ï review applicant application material for consistency,
completeness, accuracy, etc;
ï communicating with applicants on all matters related to the staffing process, including for the purpose of scheduling interviews;
ï participating in interviews;
ï conducting reference checks;
ï notifying applicants of results;
ï preparing options/notes for Informal Discussions (ID);
ï collecting and tracking (from start to finish) all material associated with the staffing action;
ï work independently, but under general supervision to complete all tasks; and
ï use Microsoft Office Word, Excel and Outlook to develop all materials.
†
```

Comment: does the file encoding match the db encoding?

Comment: Clean it up how?  What are you actually trying to do?  What have you done so far to try to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that they look like line breaks - I would go through and do a quick find/replace on all of the unwanted characters, replacing them with what you would like to change them to -- `\n` or the like. It should be fairly trivial, especially if it's all in one csv file. Hint: You can open the .csv in a plaintext editor to do the find and replace quickly, so you don't need to do it in Excel or any other CSV editor.